# unable to bind event to datetimepicker plugin

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using Trent Richardson's jQuery UI Timepicker.  I know the plugin has been modified to override $.datepicker._selectDate so that the picker will stay open when a date is selected.  That's great.

However, I have been asked to have the picker close when double-clicking a date.  Everything else remains the same, including a button for closing the picker when done, etc., only they want the double-click to work as well.

I have attempted to bind the double-click event to calendar dates in several ways (mostly variations of `$('.ui-datepicker-calendar a').bind('dblclick', function () {/*do something*/});)` -- indeed, I have attempted to bind other events as well -- and nothing seems to work.  I have tried the suggestions posted for [How to close DateTimePicker with a double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198715/how-to-close-datetimepicker-with-a-double-click) with no joy.

Is this even possible?  Do I need to modify the onSelect function to distinguish between a click and a double-click? (And how, when `event.type` is undefined?)  Am I binding to the wrong element?  (I've attempted binds on `$('.ui-datepicker-calendar a')`, `$('#ui-datepicker-div')`, `$('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar a')`, and numerous other variations.)

For the sake of completeness, here's my code:

```
$('#date-range-from, #date-range-to').datetimepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    controlType: 'select',
    dateFormat: 'M dd, yy ',
    minDate: 'Jan 01, 2010 ',
    maxDate: 'Dec 31, xxxx '.replace('xxxx', new Date().getFullYear() + 1),
    showAnim: '',
    showMinute: false,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    showTime: false
}).on('change', function () {
    var t = $(this),
        date = t.val().slice(0, 12),
        fromto = t.attr('id').replace('date-range-', ''),
        time = t.val().slice(-5);
    dashboardOpts.dateRange[fromto].date = date;
    dashboardOpts.dateRange[fromto].time = time;
}).mousedown(function () {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').toggle();
    $(this).blur();
});
$('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar a').bind('dblclick', function () {
    console.log('I just want to see if this event can be bound!');
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:**  For clarification, by "variations of ... `.bind('dblclick', ...)`" I meant that I tried `.live('dblclick', ...)` (even though I know it's deprecated) and `$(element).on('dblclick', ...)` and `$(document).on('dblclick', element, ...)`.

I have also attempted to `.stopPropagation()` and `.stopImmediatePropagation()` even though I do not believe this is a propagation issue.

I believe there is something in the datetimepicker plugin's code that is hijacking events in the calendar.  Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find it.  Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In datetimepicker's source, you can see author use an hack to disable closing when a date is selected. He calls it himself a bad hack.

Anyway, here is a workaround to able datepicker be closed when you double click on a date. 
I use `onSelect` function callback:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQh4/11/)

```
 $('#mydatepicker').datetimepicker({
     onSelect: function (e, t) {
         if (!t.clicks) t.clicks = 0;

         if (++t.clicks === 2) {
             t.inline = false;
             t.clicks = 0;
         }
         setTimeout(function () {
             t.clicks = 0
         }, 500);
     }
 });
```

So, in some way, i simulate dblclick behaviour using a timeout. I set it to 500ms but just play with this if you wish your dblclick to be more or less sensitive.

**UPDATE**

@JaredKnipp It appears that focus is set to input when month is switched (unvalid???), i don't have enough time to check it in detail, i'm sorry. As a simple workaround, you could try following snippet, add it to endDateTextBox onClose callback:

```
         var focusHandlers = $._data(endDateTextBox[0], "events").focus;
         $._data(endDateTextBox[0], "events").focus = {};
         endDateTextBox.one('focusin.datetimepicker mouseenter.datetimepicker', function () {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 $._data(endDateTextBox[0], "events").focus = focusHandlers;
                 endDateTextBox.blur();
             }, 0);
             $(this).off('focusin.datetimepicker mouseenter.datetimepicker');
         });
```

Note that if you are using jq version prior to 1.8, you have to use `$.data()` not `$._data()`  Hope it helps...

Comment: The solution works fine for me as long as I do not change months of the year.  If I change months, the datepicker dialog appears like it closes and then pops up again.  Is there any work around for this? I am implementing a date range solution.  http://pastebin.com/T8a2pUPv

Comment: @JaredKnipp updated answer with possible workaround, check to see if it fit your needs

Comment: @A.Wolff That appears to have solved the issue based on preliminary testing.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar a').dblclick(function () {
  console.log('I just want to see if this event can be bound!');
});
```

[dblclick docs](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/).

Comment: alas, no, that doesn't work.  That's just a shortcut for `.bind('dblclick, function...)` anyway.  I wish I would get an error message or something, but it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

try also `live` in jquery 1.7 or `on` in jquery 1.9 :

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar a').live('dblclick', function () {
  alert('I just want to see if this event can be bound!');
});
```

---

try to unbind `a tag` before binding it. maybe it bind with another function:

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar a').unbind('dblclick');
$('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar a').bind('dblclick', function () {
  alert('I just want to see if this event can be bound!');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.  I had already tried .live() and .on() -- both on the element and on document -- before I posted my question.  This is what I meant by variations on .bind().  The problem seems to be that something in the plugin itself is overriding these events, but I can't figure it out. :(